# securing php apache web server

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I set up an Apache web server with php-fpm support. Some guy upload a PHP shell and browsed all over my server! How can I prevent that? I already configured pool and socket for each vhost! How can fully secure my web server?

In my vhost config file:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm_test.com.sock|fcgi://test.com/"
</FilesMatch>
```

In  /etc/php-fpm.d/test.conf:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php5-fpm_test.com.sock


listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = test.com
group = test.com

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35


php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/vhosts/test.com/logs/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on

php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/session
```

Also I did these:

```
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/test.com/ test.com
chown -R test.com:test.com /var/www/vhosts/test.com
```

But still they can browse even by C99.php shell!

Comment: The biggest question is how you allowed someone to upload a php script? Go lock down your upload page. Filter on filetypes, and store uploads in a place that isn't accessible from the web.

Comment: i did it for security test ! and also i wanna let useres upload their own site in www folder !

Comment: And... what specifically are you trying to prevent? Uploads? PHP scripts being executed? Or PHP scripts being able to read certain paths? Be specific here. "Fully secure my web server" is a very vague question, and you won't get much help here.

Comment: no body can browse other vhosts directory ! in this case , the uploader user , browsed all over the linux (even root dir) i his browser by a simple shell !

Comment: Ok. Then you need to ask that one specific question: "How can I prevent a PHP script from reading my root directory." Or better yet, do some searching. This is basic permissions stuff, ensuring that php-fpm is running as a user without permissions to access those paths.

Comment: in other word , how can i config php-fpm to prevent access the other www vhosts directories !

Comment: i wanna setup something like host Cpanel . for ftp require a user and password , buy every one just can visite the site . no body shouldn'e access to browse or explore over the linux server .

Comment: i solved it by php_admin_value[open_basedir]